# OpenFrameworks - minus the GL window

Tags: c++, opencv, openframeworks

I have a project that involves OpenCV among some other media related functionality and after playing with OpenFrameworks it seems to be perfect for the task, well nearly perfect ;)

This project is actually a Flash project and I have a working connection to C++ for all the image processing for speed. The problem is that OpenFrameworks require the following code to init before the ofRunApp:

```
ofAppGlutWindow window;
ofSetupOpenGL(&window, 1024,768, OF_WINDOW); // <-------- setup the GL context
```

Is there an easy way to use the OpenCV related functionality in OpenFrameworks without opening any window? Just for the record I would prefer to use OpenFrameworks rather than vanilla OpenCV for the flexibility of OF and it's other features.

Thanks in advance,
a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'official' way to do this with openFrameworks.

Since openFrameworks has swappable renderers, you could write one to do this. But this seems to be a lot of work because many openFrameworks internal rely on a window and GL context.

You can find he most promising attempts to solve this problem [here](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php/topic,1876.0.html) and [here](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php/topic,3253.0.html). Maybe you can search the openFrameworks on your own to find probably more. Even better: feel free to start a new topic to get people see that there is a need for headless rendering.

Comment: Thanks ben, after lot's of research it definitely seems like this is going to be a major obstacle, such a shame. I'll definitely take your advice and start a new thread for headless rendering but it seems it'll be too late for my deadline but it may help others!